# Receiving "Unsupported Realm File Format" after upgraing

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm using `realm` and `react native` to write a mobile app. Everything was working fine and then I tried to open my default.realm file in the Realm Browser at which point it asked me to upgrade to a new version. I upgraded and was able to open the default.realm file in the browser, however when I opened my app in the simulator, I get the following error now:

```
Unable to open a realm path at [REALM PATH]. Unsupported Realm File Format Version
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I don't know if this is the right way to address this issue, but I just went in and deleted the default.realm file specified in the error message and it generate a new one and all is well with the world. Please let me know if there's a better solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

### Upgrade Your `realm` package in Your App.

When you updated the `.realm` file in Realm Studio, it became incompatible with older versions of Realm so the app on your simulator can no longer open up that `.realm` file.

All you should have to do is update the version of `realm` package in your application and that will move it inline with the updated version of that `.realm` database.

I had to do the same thing and ended up upgrading from 1.3.0 to 2.23.0. A big update, but then everything worked great.

If you still run into trouble after updating, I would suggest removing `node_modules`, cleaning the build and unlinking any existing Realm libraries so you're not accidentally using a cached or older version.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio. For some reason it does not prompt me with the "update to the latest version" flag like it usually does. I had to go to the [Realm Github tags](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tags) page to figure out the latest version. Fixed my problem!

Answer (score -1):

Which version of Realm React Native are you using? You should upgrade it to the latest to support the newest file format.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think I do have the latest. I have deleted my realm files and re-installed realm and still get the same error. I'm using: realm": "^1.2.0" and "react-native": "0.39.2". To be more clear, the error is  `Unable to open a realm at path '....1C32108B-C670-4BF0-839F-E05A15E34169/data/Containers/Data/Application/713F3F65-4044-4ECB-ABFA-722157F5DFD8/Documents/default.realm': Unsupported Realm file format version.`